# Can a person apply for German dependent visa from a different country other than his country of residence?

Tags: germany, singapore

i want to apply for dependent visa for my husband as i am travelling to Germany for long term on work. My husband is currently working in Singapore from the past 8 months. Can he apply for dependent visa at the German consulate in Singapore?

Comment: Wouldn't he be considered a temporary resident in Singapore?

Comment: He is a resident in Singapore if working there for 8 months.

Comment: Not only he can but he even must apply in Singapore, I suppose.

Comment: Both citizenships and possibly your resident status is required to answer this question correctly.